# C# Regular Expressions Replace String

Tags: regex, formatting

I'm not familiar with regular expressions but I'm sure it's going to be the best way to do what I want. I want to have a regular expression that replaces a string with a new string using the following formatting:

1. Every other capital letter starting from the first capital letter should be made lowercase.
2. Replace every second space with an underscore
3. Remove remaining spaces

"Some Text String Here And There Please" should become "someText_stringHere_andThere_please"

The above is only an example string. The string could be anything and have any amount of words in my situation we are looking at between only 2 words and 4 words at the moment and likely will stay that way but I'm provided you with formatting rules that no matter the length would do exactly what I need it to do.

I'd appreciate any help provided.

Comment: Did you produce a test regex that failed to do what you wanted?

Comment: I have not because unfortunately I'm having an extremely difficult time understanding regular expressions. I've looked and looked and I'm just not getting anywhere. So truly I'm open to an amazing learning guide that teaches you rather then throws bunch of stuff at you and says this does this like everything I find. Best case scenario I get an answer for this so I can complete this on time and a guide so that I can actually learn cause in a few weeks I'll be needing to use regular expressions for more then this one thing and in another project and prefer to know what I'm doing.

Comment: @FatalError0x00 If you don't understand Regex don't use it in a project,  It's only going to create a headache for you and other developers who have to work on that project

Comment: @johnny5 is right. Regular expressions are an advanced *language* topic that is trivialized by string parsing tasks. Perhaps, designing this another way is best. Your requirements, while tedious to implement, are well-defined and simple to handle.

Comment: @johnny5 and ChiefTwoPencils are correct.  You should not ask for someone to solve your problem before you learn about the subject and try to solve yourself.  Here is a site that will help you understand Regex [Regular Expression Tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) if you prefer to pursue a Regex approach and want to learn about all of the different tasks that Regex can perform.

Comment: Alright then. Thanks guys.